# display weeks between dates

Tags: mysql, sql

i am using following query to get weekly sum of hours spent for a peoject

```
SELECT SUM( hours ) AS total, 
CONCAT( spent_on,  ' - ', spent_on + INTERVAL 6 DAY ) AS weeky
FROM time_entries
WHERE project_id =1
GROUP BY WEEK( spent_on )
```

my current output is

```
20  2011-04-28 - 2011-05-04
18  2011-06-11 - 2011-06-17
17  2011-06-13 - 2011-06-19
26  2011-06-20 - 2011-06-26
```

but i also want to display those weeks that are not in time-entries.

i.e i want to display all the weeks from a given date till a date.

expected output is

```
20  2011-04-28 - 2011-05-04
0       2011-05-05 - 2011-05-11
0       2011-05-12 - 2011-05-18
.
.
.
18  2011-06-11 - 2011-06-17
17  2011-06-13 - 2011-06-19
26  2011-06-20 - 2011-06-26
```

or if not dates it should display week 1, week 2, week 3.. week n

even those weeks where there is no work-entry in the table

Answer (score 1):

Then you need a lookup table.  One with the start date of every week that you're interested in.  With that table, you can LEFT JOIN your data, and get to work :)

```
SELECT
  SUM( time_entries.hours ) AS total, 
  CONCAT( calendar.first_date,  ' - ', calendar.last_day ) AS weekly
FROM
  calendar
LEFT JOIN
  time_entries
    ON  calendar.first_day <= time_entries.spent_on
    AND calendar.last_day  >= time_entries.spent_on
    AND time_entries.project_id =1
GROUP BY
  calendar.first_day
```

Although having that lookup table my feel a bit untidy, it hardly uses any space, doesn't take long to create and populate, and is effectively a cache *(using disk space to save cpu time and query complexity)*.

Comment: @Hitesh - Yes, but you only have to do it once.  You can write a loop to do it, for 100 years of weeks, and it'll take seconds.  Then you use that table as the template that you LEFT JOIN on.

Comment: Dems, i tried this approach, created a lookup table for calendar.. but still i am not getting the rows where no hours are spent.. its bit shocking for me as well because now i am applying left join with the calendar table.. this is the output i am getting               "20 2011-04-26 - 2011-05-02"   \n  
"35 2011-06-07 - 2011-06-13"   \n  
"2 2011-06-14 - 2011-06-20"  .. expected output will have entries for 5th month as well

Comment: @Hitesh - Oh, my mistake, move the WHERE clause to the ON clause.

Comment: already did that. put the where clause in place of and time-entries.... but dint work.. rather no change..

Comment: @Hitesh - Could you add the contents of your two tables to your question, and the exact query you are now running?

Comment: calendar table has two fields week_start and week_end

2008-01-01 2008-01-07
2008-01-08 2008-01-14
2008-01-15 2008-01-21
2008-01-22 2008-01-28
2008-01-29 2008-02-04
.


time table has following fields
spent_on, projectid, hours

and following is the exact query

SELECT
  SUM( time_entries.hours ) AS total, 
  CONCAT( calendar.week_start,  ' - ', calendar.week_end ) AS weekly
FROM
  calendar
LEFT JOIN
  time_entries
    ON  calendar.week_start <= time_entries.spent_on
    AND calendar.week_end  >= time_entries.spent_on
    WHERE time_entries.project_id =3
GROUP BY
  calendar.week_start

Comment: @Hitesh - Please see my edit from yesterday.  The WHERE clause has to move to cater for the LEFT JOIN.  It's filtering out records that are NULL, which are the records your specifically trying to add in.

Comment: @Hitesh - If it works, use the upvote and accept next to the answer :)  If it was a pain in the backside, downvote ;)